# Using git with a proxy that rewrites SSL certificates

Tags: git, ssl, digital-signature, msysgit

at $WORK, we have to use an introspecting web proxy that rewrites the SSL certificate chain. I can verify this by using curl to get an https URL or running (o.k., trying to run :-) ) the firefox plugin updater.

The windows port of GIT, http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/, also complains about broken certificates. Is there a way to force it to ignore certificate problems?

Regards,
Hakan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY environment variable to true.

Ex:

```
$ env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git pull
```

Comment: On Ubuntu Precise with git 1.7.11.1 with libcurl3-gnutls 7.22.0-3ubuntu4, this does not appear to work. The proxy is a websense system.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it rewrites certificate chains, I imagine it has its *own* certificate which it returns instead of the target server's. If you want to use such a proxy of course your clients must trust *it* as well as/instead of the target server, which is just a matter of distributing the appropriate cert, or better still getting it signed by a CA. The last thing you want to do is ignore certificate problems: otherwise you may as well not use SSL at all.

Comment: What's funny about this is its probably safe to ignore SSL as the rewriting proxy probably handles *all* SSL traffic and won't let invalid certificates through (if it did let invalid certificates through and replaced with its own I'd be hopping mad as it's no longer possible to guard against MITM attacks).

Answer (score 0):

Add the proxy server certificate to your windows machine's certmgr, this, most of the time, is done by the IT department of your company (which presumably, runs the proxy that is acting as a "benevolent" man-in-the-middle)